# Explicit form for forwards Feynman-Kac formula

Tags: stochastic-processes, stochastic-calculus, parabolic-pde, feynman-kac

This might be a simple question, but I'm having trouble with it.

Consider the Cauchy problem with final condition.
\begin{equation}
\begin{cases}
\frac{\partial u}{\partial t}(t,x) + \mathcal{L}u(t,x) + k(t,x)u(t,x) = g(t,x) &\textit{in}\quad\left[0,T\right]\times\mathbb{R}\\
u(T,x)=\phi(x)&\textit{in}\quad\mathbb{R}
\end{cases}
\label{CauchyProb}
\end{equation}
where
\begin{equation}
\mathcal{L} = \frac{1}{2}\sigma^2(t,x)\frac{\partial^2}{\partial x^2} + \mu(t,x)\frac{\partial }{\partial x}.
\end{equation}
I am well aware that a solution to this problem can be given in terms of the following Feynman–Kac formula:
\begin{equation}
u(t,x)=\mathbb{E}\left[\phi(X_T^{t,x})\exp\left\lbrace\int_t^Tk(s,X_s^{t,x})ds\right\rbrace
-\int_t^Tg(s,X_s^{t,x})\exp\left\lbrace\int_t^s k(u,X_u^{t,x})du\right\rbrace ds\right]
\end{equation}
where $X_t$ is an Itô process that is described by:
\begin{equation}
dX_t = \mu(t,X_t)dt + \sigma(t,X_t)dW_t\,,
\end{equation}
with $X_0=x$.

I was wandering. What is the Feynman-Kac formula for the Cauchy problem with initial condition:
\begin{equation}
\begin{cases}
-\frac{\partial u}{\partial t}(t,x) + \mathcal{L}u(t,x) + k(t,x)u(t,x) = g(t,x) &\textit{in}\quad\left[0,T\right]\times\mathbb{R}\\
u(0,x)=\phi(x)&\textit{in}\quad\mathbb{R}
\end{cases}
\label{CauchyProb2}
\end{equation}